# Passing arguments to class methods confusion

Tags: python

I'm brand new to programming using classes.  I want to create a method that takes only one class variable and have no idea if it's even possible, nevermind how to do it. My code is working fine but it seems that there should be a more elegant solution. As you can see in the code below, the same code is virtually repeated with the main difference being whether it's "player_pieces" or "pc_pieces" being examined. So I wanted to create a separate method but I have no idea how to single out a class variable to pass to it.

The code below is finding the highest doubles in either the players or the pc's pieces.

```
       doubles = [[6, 6], [5, 5], [4, 4], [3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1], [0, 0]]

                for double in doubles:
                if double in self.player_pieces:
                    self.status = "computer"
                    self.domino_snake.append(double)
                    self.player_pieces.remove(double)
                    doubles_in_hand = True
                    break
                elif double in self.pc_pieces:
                    self.status = "player"
                    self.domino_snake.append(double)
                    self.pc_pieces.remove(double)
                    doubles_in_hand = True
                    break
```

I know this is a very elementary question and I'm probably missing something silly, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move the duplicate code outside the `if-else` block.

Comment: You don't need the break statement, if the if block is executed the else one will be ignored. Also, write the repeated logic outside the if/else block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an element from one list and appending it to another is basically moving. Let's make a method that is responsible for that one thing:

```
def move_to_snake(self, pieces, double):
    self.domino_snake.append(double)
    pieces.remove(double)
    return True
```

And use it in your code:

```
for double in doubles:
    if double in self.player_pieces:
        self.status = "computer"
        doubles_in_hand = self.move_to_snake(self.player_pieces, double)
    elif double in self.pc_pieces:
        self.status = "player"
        doubles_in_hand = self.move_to_snake(self.pc_pieces, double)

    if doubles_in_hand:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly what I needed.  I had initially tried to add self.player_pieces as an argument to a method, but I must have just been repeatedly doing something stupid because I couldn't get it to work.  This is perfect now! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can place the repetitive code in a separate function.

Secondly, I would also change the `for` loop to a `while` loop - where the loop exits if `double_in_hand` is `True` (or if we finished running on all the `doubles`).

You can also make the `double_in_hand` variable - part of an instance of the class (as it does represent part of the object's state). Then you can just initialize it to `False` before the loop, and update it to `True` if the condition is met.

You can also set the `status` variable inside of the other function, as that logic is also repetitive:

```
def another_function(self, double, status):
    self.status = status
    self.domino_snake.append(double)
    self.player_pieces.remove(double)
    self.double_in_hand = True


def your_function(self, doubles):
    self.double_in_hand = False
    while not self.double_in_hand and index < len(doubles):
        if doubles[index] in self.player_pieces:
            self.another_function(doubles[index], "computer")
        elif doubles[index] in self.pc_pieces:
            self.another_function(doubles[index], "player")
        index += 1
```

Also, the variable names `doubles` and `double` are not informative and you should consider renaming them.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `double` as an argument to `self.another_function`?

Comment: @RoyCohen Yep, I missed that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you.  This also looks like a good solution.  I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code you have is not *that* bad. Leaving it as is is pretty okay.
Still, if you want to remove the code duplication, you can use `double_in_hand` to check if the duplicated code needs to run after the if/else block:

```py
for double in doubles:
    if double in self.player_pieces:
        self.status = "computer"
        doubles_in_hand = True
    elif double in self.pc_pieces:
        self.status = "player"
        doubles_in_hand = True
    
    if double_in_hand:
        self.domino_snake.append(double)
        self.player_pieces.remove(double)
        break
```

*I'm assuming that `double_in_hand` starts out as `False`.
*I'm assuming the order of the statements doesn't matter, e.g. it doesn't matter if `doubles_in_hand = True` runs before `self.domino_snake.append(double)`

---

Another way to go about it is to use `continue` in an added `else` block. This way is more complicated so I don't like it, but it's an option.

```py
for double in doubles:
    if double in self.player_pieces:
        self.status = "computer"
    elif double in self.pc_pieces:
        self.status = "player"
    else:
        continue
    
    self.domino_snake.append(double)
    self.player_pieces.remove(double)
    doubles_in_hand = True
    break
```